# Im trying to use indexof and substring to extract text from a file but the variable index is -1 all the time what is wrong?

Tags: c#

I have a html file with some strings inside for example:

```
"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150000&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150300&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa","http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150600&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"
```

I ant to extract each line: http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150000&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa

Then the next one: http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150300&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa

This is the code im using:

In the constructor i did:

```
f = File.ReadAllText(localFilename + "test.html");
retrivingText1();


private void retrivingText1()
        {
            string startTag = "http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx";//"<Translation>";
            string endTag = "continent=europa";//"</Translation>";
            int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
            int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
            index = 0;
            w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\retrivedText1.txt");
            while (true)
            {
                index = f.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag 
                int start = index + startTagWidth;
                index = f.LastIndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // found the endTag 
                string g = f.Substring(start, index - start + endTagWidth).Trim(); //Trim the founded text so the start and ending spaces are removed.
                w.WriteLine(g);
                //break so you dont have an endless loop
                break;
            }
            w.Close();
        }
```

I know for extracting from html file its better to use htmlagilitypack or regex. But i wanted to try this time indexof and substring.

When i use a breakpoint so on the line:

```
int start = index + startTagWidth;
```

start = 2950

The next line after it index = -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer Don's answer, but if you really want to use indexof it is much easier if you prime the loop and do something like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string f = "\"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150000&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa\",\"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150300&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa\",\"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150600&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa\"";

        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = 0;
        int position = 0;

        string startTag = "http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx";//"<Translation>";
        string endTag = "continent=europa";//"</Translation>";

        startIndex = f.IndexOf(startTag);

        while (startIndex > 0)
        {
            endIndex = f.IndexOf(endTag, position);

            //parse out what you want

            position = endIndex + endTag.Length;

            startIndex = (f.IndexOf(startTag, position));

            //something here to prevent endless loop
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On the [Page you refer to](http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150000&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa%22,%22http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150300&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa%22,%22http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150600&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa) I cannot find the lines of text that you are looking for...

I think, like you also thought about, that it would be alot better using a regular expression:

```
http:\/\/www\.niederschlagsradar\.de\/images\.aspx\?jaar=-6&type=europa\.precip&datum=\d{12}&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa
```

Then you will get all the references you need for further processing.

---

**EDIT**

If you wan't to use IndexOf and SubString. You are using the LastIndexOf in the wrong way. LastIndexOf is seaching backwards in the string toward the beginning of the string.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3z4t9d.aspx)

Try to just use IndexOf instead

Comment: smerlung this is the page to refer to: http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1&continent=europa# you need to download/save this html and then when you edit it you will see the url's inside. I prefer to use the indexof and substring for the learning in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example file, I would prefer:

```
String[] sa = f.Split(',');
foreach (String s in sa)
{
    String strToWrite = f.Trim('\"');
    //write your string
}
```